# What is the point of the "take me to America" scene in Godfather?

Tags: the-godfather

What is the point of [this scene](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/0daed901-2271-4242-8a2a-150e0558984a) in
the first Godfather? It feels very random and i don't even know who is the person who yells "take me to America"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character is Fabrizzio and he is depicted in the novel (and the movie) as a person who is anxious to leave Sicily and travel to America.

> After going about fifteen miles he and his shepherds stopped in the cool green watery shade of an orange grove to eat lunch and drink their wine. Fabrizzio was chattering about how he would someday get to America.
>
> *The Godfather* - Mario Puzo

What is important about the character is that he eventually betrays Michael and, by accident, causes the death of Michael's wife, Apollonia.

From there Fabrizzio does in fact travel to America and is killed (in a deleted scene in the movie) when Michael takes is revenge on all his enemies.

> “I found him,” Michael said. “I found him a year ago. He’s got his own little pizza place up in Buffalo. New name, phony passport and identification. He’s doing very well is Fabrizzio the shepherd.”

The death is different in the novel

> The gunman said, “Fabrizzio, Michael Corleone sends you his regards.” He extended the gun so that it was only a few inches from the counterman’s skull and pulled the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

I think that line would resonate with anyone who grew up in post-ww2 Italy or the USA. I know that even in the mid 1960s a charitable organization, I think it was called Foster Children's Plan, was supporting kids in Italy while today I think of different parts of the world.

The point being that being on the losing side of WW2 negatively affected Italy for at least a generation -- it may have been pretty much what we call today a Third World nation I bet in 1945 getting to the USA was literally a dream of many an Italian (or German or Japanese or Hungarian, etc.) kid.